# sympy: modifying an expression manually

Tags: python, regex, sympy

I am aware that I can parse a Sympy expression as a tree by overriding the `print_tree` Sympy function which traverses the expression nicely.

However, is it possible to modify a specific term in the expression ?

The following are two examples of how I want to modify an expression.

**1) Example 1**

Say, I have the following expression,

```
ineq = x**2 > x + 2
```

how would I modify 'x' only in the RHS so that it becomes, for example,

```
ineq = x**2 > z**2 + 2
```

Using `subs` or `replace` functions would replace all occurrences. But I am looking for a way to replace one specific occurrence of the function.

**2) Example 2**

Is it possible to change the equality/inequality sign ?

For example, can I change `>` to `<`, or `>` to `=` in the expression ?

For example if I have the expression

```
x**2 > z**2 + 2
```

I would like to change it to,

```
x**2 == z**2 + 2
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Example 1**

Use a temporary replacement for *x**2*

```
In [1]: ineq = x**2 > x + 2

In [3]: ineq.subs(x**2, t).subs(x, z**2).subs(t, x**2)
Out[3]: 
 2    2    
x  > z  + 2
```

Nesting many *.subs( )* instead of one substitution forces the substitutions to occur one at a time.

**Example 2**

Pass the arguments to the object constructors of the other relationals:

```
In [5]: Eq(*ineq.args)
Out[5]: 
 2        
x  = x + 2

In [6]: StrictLessThan(*ineq.args)
Out[6]: 
 2        
x  < x + 2

In [7]: LessThan(*ineq.args)
Out[7]: 
 2        
x  ≤ x + 2
```

Answer (score 2):

First, note that SymPy expressions are immutable, so you can't modify them in place (any function you write will return a new expression).

You can always manipulate an expression arbitrarily by digging into its `.args`. If you have a specific expression that you want to manipulate this is often easier than trying to be clever or trying to write a more generic function to do the manipulation. For example

```
In [27]: ineq = x**2 > x + 2

In [28]: ineq.args
Out[28]:
⎛ 2       ⎞
⎝x , x + 2⎠

In [29]: ineq.args[0] > ineq.args[1].subs(x, z**2)
Out[29]:
 2    2
x  > z  + 2
```

See http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/manipulation.html for more information about this.